# Error in Nutch NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, nutch, web-crawler

I am study nutch , and I am getting this error.

I am not really sure how to fix this problem

does anyone know the way to fix this program ?

I am running nutch on the OS X mountain line..

```
apache-nutch-1.5.1 3  bin/nutch admin db -create

bin/nutch: line 104: [: -nutch-1.5.1: binary operator expected

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 3/logs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 3.logs
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 3/logs
```

I don't think `3/logs` is valid class name in java. It seems you have typo some where while running program. Make sure no typos.

Comment: I am not really sure meaning of "3/log". I don't believe that I make the logs folder. What should i do ? ...

Comment: Is it simple Java class (or) you are trying to run  an application?

Comment: nope, I was installing Nutch and I was follow http://nutch.sourceforge.net/docs/en/tutorial.html. I didn't touch more than this

Comment: It seems you missed some configuration. I never worked on this nutch, but I am certain that you are missing some configuration.